# MS dynamics CRM: iframe uncaught securityError

Tags: javascript, iframe, crm

I get this error in my code:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3860" from accessing a frame with origin "http://kerem".

Protocols, domains, and ports must match. localhost://3860 iis asp.net page and this page include,

```
 <audio controls=" controls">
       <source id="IDSource"  type="audio/mpeg" />
       </audio>   
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var path = parent.window.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_name").getValue()
           var element = document.getElementById("IDSource");
           element.setAttribute("src", path);
    </script>
```

this piece of code. Xrm.Page.getAttribute cause of Uncaught SecurityError.How can i handle this problem?

Comment: JavaScript is not allowed to communicate across different domains in this way (`localhost` and `kerem` in your case) - as reported, it's a security error (imagine a bank website in an iframe with malicious code in the outer frame, it could get your login details etc).  Are you just developing something that will at some point sit within the CRM?  You may need to get it in place on the same domain (or subdomain, then see [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain)) before continuing too far.